# image pattern matching and processing capture by the camera in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stuck with a problem that how to recognize some image pattern.

The image is a image of tiger which is capture by my iPhone device. I want to recognize the tiger Image and match it from the image store in the data base and get the information about the tiger.

I have done a lot of net surfing and found open CV is responsible for this.

Please help me with some coding point of view or any other libraries to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tried. Take a photo of an album with your iOS device and use the Google Goggles API to match it. [github code here](https://github.com/adidahiya/scrobble-goggles)